# Python: finding partial names of people

Tags: python

I have a list of people extracted from a news article as a list of strings. Example follows:

```
persons = [
    "John Doe",
    "John",
    "Johnson",
    "Murray Gell-Mann",
    "Mann",
    "Murray",
    "M",
]


def is_not_substring(sub, strings):
    for s in strings:
        if sub != s and sub in s:
            return False
    return True


fullnames = [
    s for s in persons if is_not_substring(s, persons)
]  # initial fullnames
residuals = [s for s in persons if s not in fullnames]  # others
```

After this snippet runs the *fullnames* variable will be a list of names of different people.

The *residuals* list could hold either part of the name (firstname or lastname) for one of the above people or another different person.

For example "John" could be referring to "John Doe" but not to "Johnson", hence I cannot use the plain "in" substring operator.

For the same logic "Mann" is not referring to Dr. Gell-Mann but is probably the last name of Thomas Mann, while "Murray" can be thought as referring to Gell-Mann.

Also please note that you should consider "M" as the fictional James Bond charachter and not part of "Murray Gell-Mann".

I'm not finding the right operator to separate strings that are parts of the people's names versus only substrings.

The expected final output with this example would be:

```
fullnames = ["John Doe", "Johnson", "Murray Gell-Mann", "Mann", "M"]
```

and using enum I would then transform each name to a tuple with a unique id:

```
fulltuples = [(0, "John Doe"}, (1, "Johnson"), (2, Murray Gell-Mann), (3, "Mann"), (4,"M")]
```

and then the final residuals should be:

```
residualtuples = [(0,"John"),(2,"Murray)]
```

where in the latter the number in the tuple refers to the number in the fulltuples to mean it's a co-reference.

Comment: I recommend that you look at `str.split()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Could you add expected output? It's not clear for me.

Comment: I am well aware of the split function which I could use to divide the strings on whitespaces, but I'm not wrapping my head around how to use the resulting "subnames". Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to group names by the words they contain and then use this dictionary to build a mapping between shorter names and the longest one in each group:

```
same = dict()
same.update( (word,sorted(same.get(word,[])+[name],key=len,reverse=True))
             for name in persons for word in name.split() )

nameToFull = { name:fullName for names in map(iter,same.values())
                   for fullName in names for name in names }

print(nameToFull)
{'John': 'John Doe', 'Murray': 'Murray Gell-Mann'}
```

you can then use this mapping dictionary to fix the names in the list or for other processing:

```
persons = [ nameToFull.get(name,name) for name in persons ]

['John Doe', 'John Doe', 'Johnson', 'Murray Gell-Mann', 
 'Mann', 'Murray Gell-Mann', 'M']
```